# Map gazebo world SLAM

Tags: slam, gazebo, navigation, mapping, laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys! I'm in trouble with creating the map of the willowgarage (i'm using it just for practice). I think that the problem is related to record the laser scan in the bag. I'm following this procedure for the creation of the bag and of the map:

1. roslaunch gazebo_ros willowgarage_world.launch
2. insert the robot in the environment
3. rosbag record -O example /laser_scan

For the creation of the map:

1. roscore
2. rosparam set use_sim_time true
3. rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=laser_scan
4. rosbag play --clock example
5. rosrun map_server map_saver -f map_example

From executing these commands, at the end, the server is waiting for the map without reaching any result. In the gmapping process, I have warning like:
**[ WARN] [1500976433.556165904, 15.058000000]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.gmapping.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.**

**[ WARN] [1500976494.043539452, 0.045000000]: Detected jump back in time. Clearing TF buffer.**

What is the error in the procedure that I'm following? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267310/map-gazebo-world-slam/) by [tonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/30285/tonio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to record the `tf` and `odom` topics (and `tf_static`, if applicable) when you record your bag file.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l_a_den](https://answers.ros.org/users/17996/l_a_den/) on 2017-07-26**:
Hi, allen, where does the `tf` topic comes from? What I think is that the `tf` topic is an output, not an input, there is a sensor can produce `tf` directly? Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [tonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/30285/tonio/) on 2017-07-26**:
I tried to build the map in real time without the bag through rviz but when I add the LaserScan topic, it says me that the status is error: *For frame [base_laser]: Frame [base_laser] does not exist* in the Transform voice. Are you suggesting me to use a node tf broadcaster?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2017-07-30**:
Yes -- you need tf to give the transforms needed to understand laser positions. Tf broadcaster will create the tf topic. But, if you're starting out with a new package, look into tf2 (since tf has been deprecated for some time now).